# Should I use CNAME or A record for Tumblr custom domain in case of .msk.ru TLD?

Tags: dns, tumblr

I'm setting up custom domain for tlog and already have domain name like `<business-name>.msk.ru`

Depending on official Tumblr help in case of third+ domain name I should use CNAME DNS record, not A. But it seems like I'm not so good in DNS related things. So... does `.msk.ru` domains counts as third level or not?

Comment: is msk your business name or is msk.ru a TLD?

Comment: @LiamSorsby, `.msk.ru` is a TLD as far as I know.

Comment: Also I resolved my issue, planning to close question as soon as I be able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After global DNS was finally updated I could use my Tumblr Custom Domain and now I can be sure that `.msk.ru` is a TLD.